# mongo go driver: uint always marshals to bson int64

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

The [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#hdr-Native_Go_Types) for the `bson` package states the following:

> uint, uint32, and uint64 marshal to a BSON int32 if the value is between math.MinInt32 and math.MaxInt32, inclusive, and BSON int64 otherwise.

But for some reason, `uint` always marshals into bson int64. On the other hand `int` behaves as excepted.

[Here](https://go.dev/play/p/J5Z-jn8_NSE) you can find a working example of the problem. It seems like a really simple thing I am probably missing, so I am currently not opening an issue.

Comment: If I remember correctly, mongodb does not support uint natively

Comment: bson indeed doesn't have uint, but the go driver should still marshal go uint to the correct bson type.

Comment: what do you think should be correct type?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the documentation states: "uint, uint32, and uint64 marshal to a BSON int32 if the value is between math.MinInt32 and math.MaxInt32, inclusive, and BSON int64 otherwise." 
Was just wondering why it doesn't behave according to the docs.

Comment: There appears to be an option to encode integers as their minimum size types which the entry point you are using doesn't set: https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#Encoder.IntMinSize

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the documentation was indeed wrong. [This issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-3071) was created in response to my question.

Since it seems the documentation will be updated, I guess this question can be closed if moderators think it is no longer necessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).